# How to properly add a foreign key from my own model to the EF Userprofile?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

my model classes first:

```
public class Person
{
    [Required, Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNr { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Hobbys { get; set; }
    public string SkillsToLearn { get; set; }
    public string Stand { get; set; }
    public int YearsOfWorkExperience { get; set; }
    public string HobbyProjectICTRelated { get; set; }
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserProfile profile { get; set; }

}
```

```
 [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }
        public virtual Person personprofile { get; set; }

    }
```

when i run this however it gives me this exception: The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured

i've searched this error but it doesn't clarify it for me... so i absolutely have no clue how to fix this. Basically i want to link my Person class to the Userprofiles so that i can create a login mechanism that automatically lets 1 person who makes an account on the site get 1 Profile to Edit to his own information. He's however not allowed to modify other people their accounts.

I hope this makes my problem clear and that somebody can help me :). i'm using EF 6 btw and i get the error in the class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute that comes standard with the MVC example of ASP.net

Greetings and thanks in advance, 
Marijn

Comment: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) The general consensus is yes, it should. Also, using capital I in text is considered grammatically correct, which is why I made those edits. Why did you roll it back?

Comment: because i don't exactly think that anything you did is usefull to my problem 0.o

Comment: It made your post more readable, and removed noise that is considered to be just that; noise.

Comment: i don't generally care about grammatics when i'm reading something but w/e and tbh i don't see how any of this is usefull at all.. so if you got an answer please share else just let it be....

Comment: You don't - Stack Overflow does. But as you say - whatever. I'm not about to start an edit war, I was merely curious as to your motivation for the rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with these codes in the models:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
     [Key, DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }

     public virtual Person personprofile { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Person
{
    [ForeignKey("profile"), Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills { get; set; }
    public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNr { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Hobbys { get; set; }
    public string SkillsToLearn { get; set; }
    public string Stand { get; set; }
    public int YearsOfWorkExperience { get; set; }
    public string HobbyProjectICTRelated { get; set; }
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public UserProfile profile { get; set; }
}
```